# Tensorflow: where is the documentation of 'tensorflow.python.training'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had seen code "`from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages`" many times when i read open source code. But i don't know what 'moving_averages' really do, and i want to read docs about it. I didn't found the links about docs, i need some help.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find it here [tensorflow moving average (v0.12)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/moving_averages)

edit:

As you can see from the official Tesnorflow (v1.4) [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) and the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0403762ced523c048914009b335c7626e10e5f2e/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py#L233)

Class `ExponentialMovingAverage`

Defined in `tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py`

Comment: I had seen this. But they have even different class names. In the docs, it is "tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage", but it is "tensorflow.python.training" in the code.Are they the same?

Comment: In the newest tensorflow release (v1.4) the module name is moving_averages and the class is ExponentialMovingAverage [see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0403762ced523c048914009b335c7626e10e5f2e/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py#L233)

Comment: @Ericccccc I gave you a correct answer, why downvote it?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't remember I did this. And I was sleeping just now. My reputation is less than 15, and the vote has been recorded, but do not change the  publicly displayed post score.